# Alamofire automatically escaping string in JSON object

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm sending a POST request to an api using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON and getting a weird issue where it seems Alamofire maybe automatically escaping forward slashes. Only one section of the JSON i'm sending to the server is having it's forward slashes escaped, and its a base64 image string.

I set some breakpoints and checked my local data on device and know that the data is fine and unescaped up until the point Alamofire sends off the request, but when it gets to the server, it is coming in escaped. Not sure if there is some flag I need to set to prevent this or something?

The Alamofire request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,
        submitUrl,
        parameters: ["data":completedBlob.object], //completedBlob is a SwiftyJSON object
        encoding: .JSON ,
        headers: self.submitHeaders

        ).responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    guard json["error"].isExists() else{ callback?(success: false, jsonObject: nil);return}
                    let result = json

                    Settings.setAuthToken(self.db, token: self.authToken)
                    callback?(success: true, jsonObject: result)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("An error occured processing request: \(error)")
                print(response.result.value)
            }
    }
```

Base 64 string before Alamofire sends it off:

```
data:image/png;base64, forward slashes in data here are unescaped
```

Didnt paste the entire base64 string because its huge, but all of the forward slashes in the base64 string are escaped. Here is what the server receives:

```
{"inspector":"data:image\/png;base64,forward slashes in data here are escaped.
```

it seems its even encoding the media types

> data:image/png;base64

Looked through [Alamofire documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.3.1/), cannot find any mention of this issue, so i'm starting to feel like it might not be alamofire, but im not sure what else it could be?

Details: Running Xcode 7.3 | Swift 2.2 | Alamofire 3.30 | SwiftyJSON 2.3.1 | Both installed using Carthage.

Thanks guys!

Comment: According the documentation of Alamofire, I would expect the body of the request is a JSON, looking as this:  `{"data": { ... }}`. Rationale: parameter `parameters` in function `request` is a `Dictionary` (`[String: AnyObject]`), which AF treats as JSON Object. This is serialised via NSJSONSerialization. Precondition: your `completedBlob.object` can be serialised as JSON Object. So, I don't see where `{"inspector": "data:image...}` comes from.

Comment: Similar to [SwiftyJSON issue 440 - Forward slashes escaped in quoted strings](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/440)